# javascript: check if complex object is in array

Tags: javascript

Consider the following code:

```
var queryParamCache = {};

function doThing(filter, offset)
{
  var cacheObj = {filter:filter, offset: offset};

  if (queryParamCache[cacheObj]) {
    //do something
  }
  else{
    queryParamCache[cacheObj] = true;
   //do something else
  }
}
```

as soon as queryParamCache[cacheObj] is set to true, then whenever this function is called it will always be true, no matter the values of cacheObj.

I believe it's because the check is against [object, object] instead of the actual values of filter and offset.

How do I achieve what I want ?

Comment: *"javascript: check if complex object is in array"* You haven't shown how you're creating `queryParamCache`, but regardless of how you're creating it, you're not *using* it as an array. You're using it as an object (a map).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do this:

```
queryParamCache[cacheObj]
```

you're actually doing this:

```
queryParamCache[String(cacheObj)]
```

which is (on generic objects)

```
queryParamCache["[object Object]"]
```

regardless of what's in `cacheObj`.

Consider: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/efonac/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/efonac/1/edit)

```
var a = {foo: "bar"};
var b = {bar: "charlie"};
var cache = {};

cache[a] = "Hi there";
console.log(cache[b]);  // "Hi there"
```

Both `a` and `b` get turned into the string `"[object Object]"`.

> How do I achieve what I want ?

If your goal is to have `queryParamCache` be a store of values that you can look up by using an object, you'll have to define a mechanism for turning that object into a string. Property names (keys) in JavaScript objects are **always** (for now) strings.

One way you can do that is to give your objects a different `toString` method, like this: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/efonac/2) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/efonac/2/edit)

```
function CacheEntry(filter, offset) {
  this.filter = filter;
  this.offset = offset;
}
CacheEntry.prototype.toString = function() {
  return "[Cache: " +
    this.filter + "|" +
    this.offset + "]";
};
var a = new CacheEntry("transform", 10);
var b = new CacheEntry("opacity", 22);
var cache = {};

cache[a] = "Hi there";
console.log("cache[a] = " + cache[a]); // "cache[a] = Hi there"
console.log("cache[b] = " + cache[b]); // "cache[b] = undefined"
```

There I've used a *constructor function* to assign a prototype to the objects created by the function, where that prototype has a replacement for `toString`. Constructor functions are just one way to assign prototypes; the other (new with ES5, although it can be shimmed) is `Object.create`.

Or of course, you could just assign `toString` to each object individually: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/efonac/3) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/efonac/3/edit)

```
function cacheEntryToString() {
  return "[Cache: " +
    this.filter + "|" +
    this.offset + "]";
}
var a = {filter: "transform", offset: 10};
a.toString = cacheEntryToString;
var b = {filter: "opacity", offset: 22};
b.toString = cacheEntryToString;
var cache = {};

cache[a] = "Hi there";
console.log("cache[a] = " + cache[a]);
console.log("cache[b] = " + cache[b]);
```

...but this is what prototypes are *for*, so it probably makes sense to use a prototype, either via a constructor function or `Object.create`.

Comment: Thank you very much for this comprehensive answer, one of the best I've had on SO. It makes complete sense to me now, I hadn't realized that my objects were cast to String. Thanks !